# Counting Integers In Range

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn to use a for() loop to Count integers (whole numbers) from one number to another. Here is my code so far:

```
function processLoop(earlier,later) {

    earlier = 0;
    later = 0;
    count = 0;

    for (i = earlier; i <= later; i++) {
        count = count + i;
    };

    return count;
};
```

I'm supposed to have those two parameters but it's not running. I feel that I'm not being clear enough so here are my instructions:

1. In DESIGNER create javascript 06.js with a general function: countIntegers()
   There is NO HTML page.
   There is NO EVENT HANDLER.
2. The function receives two parameters. They go between (..).
3. Use any names you want for the parameters but you could use descriptive names like this:
   first and last
4. Count all integers from the first parameter to the second.Here you just count
   instead of computing the total.
5. All you need to do is use a for() loop and return the count.
6. Return the count of the integers. Use return because this is a general function.

I'm very new to this and am not sure what I'm supposed to do here. Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your parameters back to zero, no matter what you pass in.

Get rid of those lines.

Also, use `var` to define a local variable.

```
function processLoop(earlier,later) {

    var count = 0;

    for (var i = earlier; i <= later; i++) {
        count = count + 1;
    };

    return count;
};
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm still getting a grading error... I edited the original post with the instructions on what I need to do... It should be counting the distance in whole numbers from two integers. Thanks stranger, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If `earlier` and `later` are intended to be default values that can be set if parameters are passed to the function, can use `OR` `||` operator. You should also substitute `++count` for `count = count + i` to return the difference between `earlier` and `later`. Also substituted `<` operator for `<=` operator.

```js
function processLoop(earlier, later) {

  var earlier = earlier || 0,
    later = later || 0,
    count = 0;
  // use `for` loop only if `earlier` does not equal `later`
  // and `later` is greater than `earlier`
  if (typeof earlier === "number" && typeof later === "number") {
    if (earlier !== later && later > earlier) {
      for (i = earlier; i < later; i++) {
        ++count;
      };
    } else {
      return new Error("earlier is not greater than later")
    }
    return count;
  } else {
    return new TypeError("earlier or later is not a number")
  }
};

console.log("no parameters passed to processLoop:", processLoop()
            , "\n10 passed as later:", processLoop(null, 10)
            , "\ndifference between 25 and 50:", processLoop(25, 50)
            , "\ndifference between 5 and 6:", processLoop(5, 6)
            , "\ndifference between 1 and 1:", processLoop(1, 1)
            , "\nearlier or later is not a number", processLoop("a", "b")
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function processLoop(earlier,later) {

    var count = 0;

    for (i = earlier; i < later; i++) {
        count++;
    };

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = count;
};
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="processLoop(1,3)">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Don't set the value of the parameters to `zero` inside the function. If you want to count between `earlier` and `later` and doesn't need to include `earlier` use `i < later` instead of `i <= later`.

```
function processLoop(earlier,later) {

    count = 0;

    for (i = earlier; i < later; i++) {
        count++;
    };

    return count;
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of  `<=` operator ? `processLoop(1, 1)` would write `1` to `document` , where the input numbers are equal ? _"Return the count of the integers. Use return because this is a general function."_ No value is returned from function ?

Comment: @user5953981 The function does not meet requirements described at original post, and writes an incorrect value to document

Comment: @guest271314 the count includes `earlier` number also

Comment: @John There is no "between" between `1` and `1` `processLoop(1, 1)` should return `0` , not `1`

Comment: @guest271314 when `earlier=1` the condition is `true`.ie, `1<=1` and it enters the loop.Then the `count` increments. If you don't want it to add, then use `i <=later`

Comment: @John See requirement 4 at OP: _"Count all integers from the first parameter to the second.Here you just count instead of computing the total."_ There are no whole numbers between `1` and `1` . See also requirement 6: _"Return the count of the integers. Use return because this is a general function."_ No value is returned from the function at your Answer

Comment: @guest271314 If i am correct, he just need to count the numbers between the provided values and no need to compute the total. Here I used `document.write()` for my testing purpose. He can simply `return` instead. **Note**: I edited my answer. And the last, it is his duty to check whether the parameters are numbers or not. Here he just need help on the `for` loop.

Comment: @user5953981 Accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to experiment with answers that *interpret* the question because it is a bit vague. If you want to count integers between real numbers x and y, it is really important to know if the interval is open or closed.

I don't support writing code in general but in this case it's the best answer. The following code counts integers in a closed Real interval, [earlier, later]:

```
function countIntegers(earlier, later)
{   earlier = Math.ceil(earlier);
    later = Math.floor( later);
    for( var i = earlier, count = 0; i <= later; ++i, ++count);
    return count;
}
```

You may need to look up what `Math.ceil` and `Math.floor` do as well as experiment with combinations of open and closed intervals until you find the one that gets marked correct. Enjoy :-)